# I want to intercept and change one field right before Context.SaveChanges() in ADD Controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If no Batch_ID exists for this user, I make one. This works. The record saved was using Batch_ID = 0 and right before saving, I create batch_id and want to use it for the Row's batch_id column.

```
if(Session["ThisBatch"].Equals(0))
{
    var newbatchid = CheckAndMakeBatchIfNone();
}

//RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I'D PREFER TO INTERCEPT AND CHANGE
// THE Batch_ID.Value TO newbatchid variable contents. 
//THEN I SAVE. HOW CAN I JUMP INTO bucket, CHANGE THAT FIELD, AND JUMP OUT? 
//bucket is the Model the Add View is hooked to.

_db.AddToBactiBucket(bucket);
_db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("AddColiform");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you want to do only happens when `Session["ThisBatch"].Equals(0)` is true, just set `bucket.Batch_ID` to `newbatchid` right after `newbatchid` is created

```
if (Session["ThisBatch"].Equals(0))
{
    var newbatchid = CheckAndMakeBatchIfNone();
    bucket.Batch_ID = newbatchid;
}

_db.AddToBactiBucket(bucket);
_db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("AddColiform");
```

Comment: Yes. That works. Thank you very much. It if was a snake it would have bit me. I knew it was possible somehow without using a forklift to change a lightbulb.